# Ext.ux.grid.RowEditor adding tooltip for save and cancel button

Tags: javascript, extjs

I need to add tooltip message for Ext.ux.grid.RowEditor save and cancel button like for save("save the xxxx records"),cancel ("cancel the record saving").

I am unable to add tooltip property to button configuration area. like below code

```
 var editor = new Ext.ux.grid.RowEditor({
    saveText: 'Submit',
    monitorValid: true,
    tooltip :'save the xxxx records'// like this

});
```

how to add the tool tip for the specified button ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please initialize tool tips for it to work:

Ext.QuickTips.init();

Comment: tool tip is working for all the components like buttons ..etc. i think there is no tooltip property provide in row editor button...